# How can I use FJsonSerializer::Deserialize() to deserialize JSON in Unreal Engine?

Tags: json, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I am trying to Deserialize Json using FJsonSerializer in Unreal engine 4 but am getting an unresolved external symbol error LNK2019. I understand what LNK2019 is but in this situation I don't see what would be causing it.

This code is placed inside an EdModeTookit for my editor plugin.

**My Code**

```
//JSON object for test
FString JsonString = "{'word': 'hello'}";

//JSON object to hold result
TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> JsonObject;

//JSON reader
const TSharedRef<TJsonReader<TCHAR>> Reader = TJsonReaderFactory<TCHAR>::Create(JsonString);

//Deserialize
if (FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(Reader, JsonObject)) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Deserialized JSON"));
}
```

When I compile I get 38 LNK2019 unresolved symbol errors. Here are the first 3

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl FJsonValueString::FJsonValueString(class FString const &)" (__imp_??0FJsonValueString@@QEAA@AEBVFString@@@Z) referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(class TSharedRef,0> const &,struct FJsonSerializer::StackState &)" (??$Deserialize@_W@FJsonSerializer@@CA_NAEBV?$TSharedRef@V?$TJsonReader@_W@@$0A@@@AEAUStackState@0@@Z)  BayArea_I45 D:\Doccuments\Unreal Projects\BayArea_I45\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.TrafficSim.cpp.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl FJsonValueString::~FJsonValueString(void)" (__imp_??1FJsonValueString@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl FJsonValueString::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GFJsonValueString@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)  BayArea_I45 D:\Doccuments\Unreal Projects\BayArea_I45\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.TrafficSim.cpp.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl FJsonValueNumber::FJsonValueNumber(double)" (__imp_??0FJsonValueNumber@@QEAA@N@Z) referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(class TSharedRef,0> const &,struct FJsonSerializer::StackState &)" (??$Deserialize@_W@FJsonSerializer@@CA_NAEBV?$TSharedRef@V?$TJsonReader@_W@@$0A@@@AEAUStackState@0@@Z) BayArea_I45 D:\Doccuments\Unreal Projects\BayArea_I45\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.TrafficSim.cpp.obj   1

I really don't know why I am getting errors since this code seems to match the documentation and I have seen others claiming to have used similar code successfully.

Comment: Did you add the library in linker dependencies or with #pragma comment(lib,"somejson.lib") ?

Comment: FJsonSerializer is part of the unreal engine libraries and should be included in the engine setup I think. Is that not the case? @MichaelChourdakis

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis It turned out that I needed to add "Json" to the private dependency module names list. Thanks for the advice.